# Ban Specific IP's on VPS

Tags: linux, ssh, firewall, iptables

I have a case where I want to ban specific IP address on my VPS.
To ban the IP's I use SSH Access with this code:

```
iptables -I INPUT -s my-ip-here -j DROP
```

The case wich I want to ban is as following.
Ex:

I have an IP address in following format
84.252.55.106 i.e. The first three octets are always same 84.252.55 and only the last octet changes everytime when I got the spammer.

Can I ban 84.252.55 and how will it reflect on the server?

Answer (score 9):

sure, you just want to write out your rule with a subnet mask. So it would look like:

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 84.252.55.0/24 -j DROP
```

Comment: Beat me by over a minute and no blue bar!